# How to create link that can be followed in SFTP?

Tags: permissions, symbolic-link, sftp

SFTP jails the user into his home dir.  Let's say I have two users.  What if I'd like to share files and folders between them both?!  Is there a way?
  Is it possible through links?  I tried out with "ln -s userFolder" but links are shown as files in the SFTP client.  Is it just matter of setting the right permissions for the link or the linked folder?

Comment: What sftp client are you using?  When I use sftp in a terminal or in a browser (`sftp://localhost`), I can move to any folder including root.

Comment: WinSCP for SFTP access to the my Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use bind mounts:

```
mount -o bind ~user1/some/folder ~/user2/another/folder
```

SFTP should show the same contents for both directories. Bind mounts are a common way to make directories available inside chroots.

Comment: For clarification, `~user1/some/folder` is the target folder here